# Using Select with a function on 3d Table

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

From the following 3d-`Table`

```
t1={{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 4/3}}, {{1, 0}, {2, 1/2}, {3, 1}}, {{1, -1}, {2,
0}, {3, 2/3}}}
```

I want to use `Select` for getting all pairs where the second `Part` is an `Integer`. So that I would get

```
{{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{1, -1}, {2, 0}}}
```

I can do it by

```
Pick[t1, Map[IntegerQ /@ #[[All, 2]] &, t1]]
```

But there should be more elegant ways to do it. How to use `Select` or `Select` with  `Function` or some other twist?

Comment: `Select[IntegerQ@#[[2]] &]/@t1` or `Cases[{_, _Integer, ___}] /@ t1`?

Comment: Great! Compact and easy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select[IntegerQ@#[[2]] &] /@ t1

Cases[{_, _Integer, ___}] /@ t1

DeleteCases[t1, {_, Except[_Integer], ___}, {2}]

Pick[t1, t1[[All, All, 2]], _Integer]
```

all give

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{1, -1}, {2, 0}}}
> ```

If the sublists in the innermost layer are pairs of numbers (as in the example in OP) you can also use

```
Map[Select[IntegerQ@*Last]]@t1
Cases[{_, _Integer}] /@ t1
DeleteCases[t1, {_, Except[_Integer]}, {2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t1 = {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 4/3}},
      {{1, 0}, {2, 1/2}, {3, 1}},
      {{1, -1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2/3}}};
```

---

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[#, {s : {_, _Integer, ___}} :> s] & /@ t1

(*{{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{1, -1}, {2, 0}}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[#, {___, s : {_, _Integer, ___}, ___} :> s] & /@ t1

(*{{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{1, -1}, {2, 0}}}*)
```

Or using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[t1, Position[t1, {_, _?(Not@*IntegerQ)}] -> Nothing]

(*{{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{1, -1}, {2, 0}}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list =
  {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 4/3}},
   {{1, 0}, {2, 1/2}, {3, 1}},
   {{1, -1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2/3}}};
```

Define elimination pattern

```
e = {_, _?(Not @* IntegerQ)};
```

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list /. e :> Nothing
```

{{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{1, -1}, {2, 0}}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[Position[e] @ list] @ list
```

{{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{1, -1}, {2, 0}}}